# Can I implement operator overrides in typescript?

Tags: operator-overloading, typescript

Say I am creating a Dictionary class in typescript. Is there a way to have operator overrides so I can define the operator "[string]" instead of having to use the function get(string)?

Comment: dart can. But dart has it's own problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have operator overloading. JavaScript does not have a notion of this.

You *can* override toString, though:

```
class Thing {
    toString() {
        return 'I am a Thing!';
    }
}

var x = new Thing();
console.log('X says ' + x); // Prints "X says I am a Thing!"
```